# User don’t have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Whenever a new user added to the directory tries to deploy custom azure templates, they get the following validation error -
**User don't have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action**

Following roles are already granted -
1. Global Administrator access in Azure AD
2. Owner role assignment at the subscription level
3. Contributor access at management Group level

Answer (score 2):

Even as a Global Admin, you may not have access to all subscriptions and management groups for deploying the template.

Please try [elevating your access](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin) and making sure you have the [Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#az_role_assignment_create-examples) role applied.

Comment: Thanks Marliee, Have already tried elevating access but still facing same issue